# Hyperbolic Sine Function

Tags: exponential-function

Show that $\sinh(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$

I know that $\sinh(x)=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ but I can't see how inputting the set of real numbers gets the real numbers back as $e^x \gt 0$

Comment: `...as e^x > 0` The difference of two positive numbers can be negative. Check out the limits at $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $-e^{-x}<0$ and $-e^{-x} \to -\infty$ as $x\to-\infty,$ while $e^x\to0$ as $x\to-\infty.$

This function

- is everywhere increasing, as demonstrated by the fact that its derivative is everywhere positive, and
- is everywhere continuous, and
- approaches $\pm\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ respectively.

Thus the intermediate value theorem can be used to show that the image of this function is all of $\mathbb R.$

Comment: So because it approaches infinity from both sides then it also takes any value in between? From the intermediate value theorem

Comment: @JoannaM : Yes. $\qquad$

Comment: @JoannaM: Except it doesn't approach infinity from both sides (how would that be possible?!?), it approaches “both infinities”. $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.